# error : undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, struct

I'm coding in C language and can't find out what is the error.It keeps telling me that 
First:
in this line

```
temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

the `Node` is undeclared and first use is in this function.but I think I've declared it before.

Second:
in the same line

> "expected expression before ')' token"

it points to the `(Node*)`

and Third :

> "expected declaration or statement at end of input."

while it points to the closed `}` of main.

For the first one I've searched and found out it's because of C89 and I have to declare all the variables at the top of my functions.I did but the error is still there.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>

 struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;

void Add(int x){
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void print(){
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("List is:");
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf(" %s",temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    head = NULL;
    Add(3);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use a linked list.

Comment: "For the first one I've searched and found out it's because of C89 and I have to declare all the variables at the top of my functions." No you have to declare them before you use them. Same goes for functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code

```
 temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

should be

```
 temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

or, for better,

```
 temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

eliminating the issue, as you [need not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

The error was, however, because you missed the `struct` keyword there.

To address the third error,

> *"expected declaration or statement at end of input."*

well, you missed the ending `}` for the `print()` function.

FWIW, you should always check the validity of the returned pointer by `malloc()` and family of functions before making use of it.

Having said that,

> *For the first one I've searched and found out it's because of C89 and I have to declare all the variables at the top of my functions*

is not true. Yes, in C89, you needed to declare all the variables at top, but that did not allow you to *skip* the `struct` keyword, anyway.

Comment: It worked but doesn't malloc() return a void or NULL pointer?

Comment: @SamanNourkhalaj yes, right.

Comment: Perhaps a remark would be in order that the issues (declare before use, `struct` cannot be omitted and a cast is not necessary) is specific to C (89) and different in C# and C++. (Could be that the OP has C++ or C# experience.)

Comment: `temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);` is preferable, then you have a visual check of allocating the right amount of space

Comment: @M.M Added that too. :)

Comment: Thanks alot :)
and could you help me with the third one?

Comment: No.It's still there.

Comment: I don't know I'm blind or what..Thanks again.

Comment: @SamanNourkhalaj [You're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).